# Facebook Like-Box only displays in Safari

Tags: facebook, safari, facebook-likebox

I currently have a Like-Box that is only visible while I'm in Safari on my MacBook.

The following are unable to view the like-box (that I have tested so far):
Chrome,Safari (mobile) (iPhone4,4S,5,iPad), Firefox

Is functionality restricted to a certain Java setup?  I pulled the code directly from Facebook and have included the Java as they recommend.

Thanks in advance!

Code in question:

Facebook-supplied block:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MYAPPID";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

LikeBox:

```
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/MyPage/MyID" data-       send="false" data-width="60" data-show-faces="true"></div>
            </div>
```

Please Note that I have deidentified my Page and ID, thanks.

Comment: Can you post the snippet code that you use to display the like box?

Comment: The code snippet has been added to the original question and has been deidentified. Thanks again.

Comment: How do you view the page on Safari (macbook) different to Chrome? Do you deploy to staging environment / local webserver and access through http:// ?